# Common Navigation Menu drawer In Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-framelayout

I need to add navigation drawer menu in my android application. my application has many modules so i can't code each activity to display navigation menu. so i decided to put the navigation menu code in my base activity. so each activity extends this base activity. navigation drawer menu's are working properly but the problem is activity components are not working. i don't know what is happening. is there any changes needed? Thanks in advance.

```
baseActivity.java 
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
RelativeLayout fullLayout;
DrawerLayout dLayout;

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    fullLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.activity_base, null);
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) fullLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    ListView dList = (ListView) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    dLayout = (DrawerLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
    setContentView(fullLayout);

    String[] menu = new String[] { "Home", "Android", "Windows", "Linux",
            "Raspberry Pi", "WordPress", "Videos", "Contact Us" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu);

    dList.setAdapter(adapter);
    dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

    dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            dLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    });
    }};
```

activity_base.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="sas.mobi.lakshmi.main.BaseActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

homeActivity.java

```
public class HomeAndSettingActivity extends BaseActivity {
private Button btnAccount;
private Button btnCollection;
private Button btnOthers;
private Button btnTempExit;
private Button btnExit;
private AdminDS adminDS;
private AdminDO adminDO;
private FinanceDS financeDS;
private PartnerPaymentDS paymentDS;
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_and_setting);
    initializeComponents();
    btnAccount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AccountRegHomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        btnCollection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        CollectionHomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        btnOthers.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        OthersHomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        btnTempExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                financeDS = new FinanceDS(getApplicationContext());
                boolean isUps = financeDS.closeActiveCurrentFinances();
                if (isUps) {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

}

/**
 * method to initialize components
 */
private void initializeComponents() {
    btnAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAccount);
    btnCollection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCollection);
    btnOthers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOthers);
    btnTempExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTempExit);
    btnExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
}};
```

acitivity_home.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAccount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:text="@string/btnAccount"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCollection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:text="@string/btnCollection"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOthers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:text="@string/btnOthers"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTempExit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:text="@string/btnTempExit"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnExit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:text="@string/btnExit"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

this home activity and common navigation drawer menu's showing properly, but the component inside the home activity is not working.but the drawer components are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the main xml into this way and load the sidemenu into side menu frame:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          tools:context="sas.mobi.lakshmi.main.BaseActivity" >

         <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/side_menu"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It's working dude. I've added some enhancement . It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use fragments to Achive the Navigation Draw use cannot do so good with activities as its very simple you need replace fragment on each call of on your menu please find the below link http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/
or you can create new project in android studio by selecting nav ui from a new project

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I've added some enhancement, it works. I just need to know something, is really fragment is easy to make navigation Drawer compare to my design. it's easy means, i'd like to try. Thank you. :)

Comment: upvote if u like my answer, yes just try a sample on fragment where u can play lot on a single screen

Comment: sure dude :) do you have any link to refer ?.

Comment: @chellapandik  understand fragments and fragment life cycle first from developers.android and try to execute simple app from many example site you google and get it done http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/05/android-working-with-fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

As mencioned [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) you need to move your `FrameLayout` with id `content_frame` inside `DrawerLayout` something like that

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="sas.mobi.lakshmi.main.BaseActivity" >



<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```